# Retrieve Form Data From HTML Form with VBA

Tags: html, regex, forms, vba

I'm trying to write a Macro that retrieves data on all HTTP Post forms from a webpage, and then displays the possible inputs as column headings in a worksheet.  (Later I'll write another macro that constructs the appropriate requests based on input from the rows below.)

I've spent a day trying to parse the HTML with regex, (classic rookie mistake, right?), and it's a disaster.  Nothing seems to work for more than a couple of webpages.

My question is sort of a big picture one.  Should it be able to work with REGEX? Should I be taking an entirely different approach?  Is this too big a task for someone who doesn't know a whole lot about html, and web development more broadly?   I thought it would be a simple project, but it just doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use regex.  use an html parser.  Since you said you're using vba, I'll make a guess that you have excel installed.  excel has a "import data from web" function that works on any well formed html table.

and if that doesn't work, most platforms that have vba also have a web browser control of some kind.  load your target web page in an instance of said control, and access the table you want with the DOM's methods.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The problem is that I'm not trying to pull in form data, but rather get the metadata on possible http post requests so that I can change the variable values and send a query.

Comment: Dynamically, at runtime?  Use the DOM object, and look for `form` elements.  You'll even be able to adjust the values directly, and send via the web page, instead of mucking about with an XHR.

Comment: the dom suggestion REALLY helped me out, thanks so much.  I've currently got a version of this working with an internet explorer object, but it's really slow and clunky.  Do you know of a better way to retrieve/submit the DOM object?  I'm currently trying to do it with XMLHTTP, but it throws errors for almost every url.

Comment: an XmlHttpRequest object, or XHR, isn't intended to manage full web pages. .com a semi-automated browser may be your best bet, unless you want to hard-core the http requests yourself.  Turning off images and/or JavaScript in the ie object may improve performance, but as a general solution you won't find many better options.

Comment: also, if it's a SPECIFIC form that you or your customer control (or had an api), you should create a http request in code instead of mucking about with a DOM.